# Apache Camel with LinkedIn Api

Tags: spring, apache-camel, linkedin-api

I have to implement Apache Camel and Spring with LinkedIn API data access. Can you please tell me steps like how should i access LinkedIn API with Camel and Spring. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the official docs?  At the bottom of the docs you can find some use cases with which you can kick start what you really want to achieve with the Camel LinkedIn component and the API.
http://camel.apache.org/linkedin.html 
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/camel-2.19.1/components/camel-linkedin/camel-linkedin-component/src/main/docs/linkedin-component.adoc

> The following route gets user’s profile:
>
> ```
> from("direct:foo")
>     .to("linkedin://people/person");
> ```
>
> The following route polls user’s connections every 30 seconds:
>
> ```
> from("linkedin://people/connections?consumer.timeUnit=SECONDS&consumer.delay=30")
>     .to("bean:foo");
> ```
>
> The following route uses a producer with dynamic header options. The personId header has the LinkedIn person ID, so its assigned to the CamelLinkedIn.person_id header as follows:
>
> ```
> from("direct:foo")
>     .setHeader("CamelLinkedIn.person_id", header("personId"))
>     .to("linkedin://people/connectionsById")
>     .to("bean://bar");
> ```

The LinkedIn API itself is broad so it's hard to tell what exact steps are needed to achieve what you want to do with it.